# Bulk select using Spring

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring

Is there a way to do a bulk select for below query using Spring alone?

E.g.

```
select * from university where name='x' and age=y and gender='z'
```

Where `x,y` and `z` come from list such as :

```
 [[x1, y1, z1],[x2, y2, z2],[x3, y3, z3]..]
```

Comment: Spring doesn't do any "selects". You have to use something else, like JDBC, for example.

Comment: Why you don't use **IN** operator for example `..WHERE name IN :listValues`

Comment: To answer the question asked: yes there is.

Comment: @YCF_L Are you suggesting to fetch all data and apply filter?

Comment: @TheHeadRush Is there a way to pass list such as this to Spring and expect that it performs the computation only once?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve it using spring, you will have to create 3 lists of name, age and genders as follows.

```
    nameList = [x1,x2,x3,...]
    ageList = [y1,y2,y3,...]
    genderList = [z1,z2,z3]
```

You can then write the code as below

```
    @Autowired
    NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = ...

    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("nameList", nameList);
    params.put("ageList", ageList);
    params.put("genderList", genderList);
    String sql = "select * from university where name IN (:nameList) and age IN (:ageList) and gender IN (:genderList)";
    jdbcTemplate.queryForList(sql, params, <yourRowMapper>);
```